# "Review vs in reviewing "

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, phrases

I am writing a formal email to thank the employer for reviewing my application:

**I am thankful to you for your time and patience to review my application.**

But the Grammarly tool corrected me:

**I am thankful to you for your time and patience in reviewing my application.**

I am still doubtful. I am not satisfied with the internet search. Please help.

Comment: (1) is incorrect. 'I am thankful to you for the time you have taken to review my application, and for your patience' works. But (2) is crisper.

Comment: "I am thankful to you" is not particularly idiomatic. How about simply stating, "Thank you for your time and patience in reviewing my application"?

Answer (score 1):

Use "in reviewing" because your main sentence is present tense through the start of "I am...." A good way to compare is to really make it obvious by stating "I am presently thankful...because of your present review." It would be a weirder context if you were to say "I am presently thankful...because of your future review."

This is for a resume, so signal to your reviewer that you expect that the application has already been reviewed.

However, I would still revise the sentence all together. Refer to Mark Hubbard's explanation and suggestion.